# Apache2: Dual Stack mode IPV6 / IPV4 for existing IPV4 hostings

Tags: apache-2.2, ipv6, ipv4

I'm planning to run my hostings in the IPV4/IPV6 dual stack mode for a lot of hostings / IPs. Short Apache example:

ports.conf

```
Listen 199.192.201.82:80
NameVirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80

Listen [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80
NameVirtualHost [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80
```

VirtualHost config

```
<VirtualHost 199.192.201.82:80 [2607:ff50:0:21::2]:80>
```

I think, that's the common and recommended way.
But maybe you have some experience with the integration of IPV6 on existing hostings and know a better way?

for example to forward IPV6:80 with iptables to IPV4:80? or to use rinetd?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a normal Apache dual-stack setup.